# Seeking InSAR Data?

Tags: data, insar

Where can I fnd InSAR Data which is freely accessible?

I tried various sites but in the end, they lead to the page these resources are paid.

I need it for earthquake analysis.

Comment: This question is probably better askeded in [opendata.se]. Please take the [Tour], which will help you understand the purpose of GIS SE.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think that one good example to start off with is [SLC SAR data for Bam earthquake](https://earth.esa.int/web/guest/data-access/sample-data/-/asset_publisher/tg8V/content/bam-earthquake-iran-1622) freely available on ESA portal. You can also find data for other earthquakes like [L'Aquila earthquake](https://earth.esa.int/web/guest/data-access/sample-data/-/asset_publisher/tg8V/content/l-rsquo-aquila-earthquake-italy-6349;jsessionid=257C11DDA80630B561B629E4D15213A1.jvm1?redirect=https%3A%2F%2Fearth.esa.int%2Fweb%2Fguest%2Fdata-access%2Fsample-data%3Bjsessionid%3D257C11DDA80630B561B629E4D15213A1.jvm1%3Fp_p_id%3D101_INSTANCE_tg8V%26p_p_lifecycle%3D0%26p_p_state%3Dnormal%26p_p_mode%3Dview%26p_p_col_id%3Dcolumn-1%26p_p_col_count%3D2) there. 
Data from newer SAR sensors like TerraSAR-X can be found at [saredu.dlr.de](https://saredu.dlr.de/data)